# Make UILabel text size fit its frame

Tags: ios, interface-builder, uilabel, constraints, xcode7

I have a UIImageView that its height changes depending on the device's screen height. I have a UILabel with a height that is equals to the height of the UIImageView set in interface builder.

I've set the font size as big as I need it for larger devices, and with auto shrink minimum font value of 14 so that it scales down when running on smaller screen devices. The problem is that somehow it is not scaling down, the label's frame is correct, but the text is bigger and gets clipped on the top and bottom. Is there a way of making a UILabel text size fits the frame size, and when I mean frame size I mean the height of the frame, within interface builder?

Comment: Saw that, but I'm using interface builder.

Comment: Then use flexible height option and for iOS>=8 it will do automatically for you

Comment: When you say flexible height, you mean the size of the frame? The uilable frame size is good. It is the text the one that it is not scaling down to fit the frame size. Even though I have autoshrink selected.